# numpy.in1d hanging/long run time

Tags: arrays, numpy

I have two numpy arrays, ar1 is length 37,015,400 and ar2 is length 25,000. I want to return the values of ar1 that are in ar2, and also the indices of ar1. To do this, I have used the np.in1d() function. The values of the array will always be strings, even if entirely composed of integers. The following code demonstrates exactly what I want, and runs in under a minute on my machine:

```
ar1 = np.array([str(i) for i in np.arange(0,37015400)])
ar2 = np.array([str(i) for i in np.arange(0,25000)])
indarr = np.asarray(range(0,len(ar1 )))
vals = ar1[np.in1d(ar1, ar2)]
indices = indarr[np.in1d(ar1, ar2)]
```

The problem I am having is that when used on *actual* data, this process runs indefinitely (killed after 45 minutes). I had my program print out the type and shape of the two arrays that it was using, and the below is a direct copy paste:

```
ar1 shape (37015400,) <class 'numpy.ndarray'> ar2 shape <class 'numpy.ndarray'> (25000,)
```

I also had it print the two arrays:

```
ar1:
    ['100000016587' '100000019688' '100000040778' ... '999999946478'
     '999999982896' '999999992154']

ar2:
    ['833004729085' '999821141210' '107560272544' ... '976513345947'
     '514020550330' '646320590498']
```

I checked and every value of the two arrays is a string. I have tried everything and I cannot figure out why this program is hanging. What could be causing this type of error? What could be contributing to the significantly increased runtime?

Comment: You may have to look at the `in1d` code.  It takes different approaches depending on the data (size, sorted, etc).  Basically it concatenates the arrays, sorts and looks for duplicates.

Comment: How much bigger is your actual data than your toy data?

Comment: Btw, you end up computing `in1d` twice, which isn't doing you any favors. You can save the result of `np.in1d(ar1, ar2)` as a mask, which is a cheap way to reduce your runtime dramatically.

Comment: @Tgsmith61591 actual data is the exact same size as the example. There has to be something going on that I am missing because I can put ar1 in a dataframe and use pd.series.isin(ar2) and it runs in under 30 seconds. I may submit this as my answer, but I was hoping to use pure numpy as it is generally faster.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem, it took me hours for in1d computation with a huge dataset. Finally I did it using a simple loop which went more faster. For my case it was a `datetime` object comparison. It's like doing `in1d(t1,t2)` (t1 the biggest dataset).

```
tmp=0
t_out,y_out,idx=[],[],[]
for i in range(t2.shape[0]):
    for j in range(tmp,t1.shape[0]):
        if t1[j]==t2[i]:
            t_out.append(t1[j])
            y_out.append(y1[j])
            idx.append(j)
            tmp=j 
        if t1[j]>dt2[i]+timedelta(0,900):
            break;
```

You can replace the last `if`condition by `if j>i+some_threshold` if you aren't using time series (y=f(t)).

Comment: MATLAB `ismember` function does it faster. It will be better to save your two variables into a `.mat` file back and fourth.